# ValueError: shapes (6497,12) and (6497,12) not aligned: 12 (dim 1) != 6497 (dim 0)

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, neural-network, sigmoid

I have trouble figuring out what went wrong here. Could someone maybe help me out? I think it's regarding this code:

```
 synapse = np.empty((6497,12))

x_range = np.linspace(-20,20,40,dtype=np.float)
y_range = np.linspace(-20,20,40,dtype=np.float)
errors = []
_x = []
_y = []

for _x in x_range:
    synapse[0]=_x
    for _y in y_range:
        synapse[1]=_y
        
        # model
        layer_0 = x
        layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer_0,synapse))
        
        # RMSE
        error = np.mean(np.sqrt((layer_1-y)**2))
        errors.append(error)
```

The traceback in the error message includes these lines:

```
File "C:\...\temp.py", line 86, in <module> layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer_0,synapse)) 
File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in dot
ValueError: shapes (6497,12) and (6497,12) not aligned: 12 (dim 1) != 6497 (dim 0)
```

Comment: Can you include the full traceback, especially including the line in your code where the error came from?
Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032685/numpy-valueerror-shapes-not-aligned

Comment: File "C:\...\temp.py", line 86, in <module>
    layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer_0,synapse))

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in dot

ValueError: shapes (6497,12) and (6497,12) not aligned: 12 (dim 1) != 6497 (dim 0)

Comment: @SarahMesser The previous comment is the traceback and I don't know, what to do. I know it's something with shapes but I cannot pin down the mistake in my code :/

Comment: It looks like the orientation of the matrices matches when it shouldn't. If you're planning to do matrix multiplication, try inserting an np.transpose() around either layer_0 or synapse, inside the np.dot() See also the definition of np.dot(): https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html  If you're planning on doing element-wise multiplication, you probably don't want to use np.dot().

Comment: @SarahMesser Thank you! I did the np.transpose , however now I get a new error :Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:...\scapbook.py", line 86, in <module>
    layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(np.transpose(layer_0,synapse)))

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in transpose

  File "C:\Users...\fromnumeric.py", line 658, in transpose
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'transpose', axes)

  File "C:\Users\...\fromnumeric.py", line 58, in _wrapfunc
    return bound(*args, **kwds)

ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 6497

Comment: I think you should only have layer_0 _or_ synapse inside the np.transpose(), _not_ _both_.  Also, please include "things you've tried" in the original question so folks don't have to dig through comments for them.  (The main question also allows much more readable formatting.)